# Two Job Titles In User Profile

Tags: user-profile

I have a user that when they look at their profile from the peoplepicker they have two job titles and two managers.

Has anyone come across this before as I cant work out where the information is being pulled from.

Just as an aside if I or anyone else looks at their profile we only see the one job and manager.

[image: SharePointProfile]

Comment: version of SharePoint? which UPS sync are you using? add more info please.

Comment: Sorry, this is SharePoint online and we Azure AD connect to sync to office 365.

Comment: Could you check and confirm if there are two jobTitle properties being present in the User Profiles? For this, you would require SharePoint Administrator permissions and then navigate as following: Admin>SharePoint>User Profiles>Manage User Profiles.